# Culling mask for GPU instanced mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, culling, gpu-instancing

My game has 2 cameras.

I'm instancing a bunch of grass and I want the second camera to not render the grass. How can I do this?

The grass is instanced via DrawMeshInstancedIndirect.

Comment: camera: If null (default), the mesh will be drawn in all cameras. Otherwise it will be drawn in the given Camera only.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I didn't understand. I have 2 cameras, only one should render the GPU instanced mesh, the other one shouldn't.

Comment: **camera** is an argument of DrawMeshInstancedIndirect, and you should properly set it.

Comment: Please, write it as an answer so I can properly mark as correct! Didn't know DrawMeshInstancedIndirect had a camera property! Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`DrawMeshInstancedIndirect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawMeshInstancedIndirect.html) has an argument "camera", its description is:

> If null (default), the mesh will be drawn in all cameras. Otherwise it will be drawn in the given Camera only.

To draw meshes in a specific camera, just pass this camera instance to the method.

```
Camera cameraToDraw;

Graphics.DrawMeshInstancedIndirect(
    mesh, 
    submeshIndex,
    material,
    bounds,
    buffer,
    camera: cameraToDraw);
```